# C# Android HMAC result

Tags: java, c#, android, hmac

I am using the following code in c# for HMAC conversion:

```
 string RawData = "data";
  string sharedKey = "my-key";
 byte[] signature = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(RawData);
 var KeyByteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sharedKey);


            using (HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(KeyByteArray))
            {
                byte[] signatureBytes =hmac.ComputeHash(signature);

         var ContentBase64String =(Convert.ToBase64String(signatureBytes));

                Console.WriteLine(ContentBase64String );
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
```

And the following in Java:

```
 String   RawData="data";
 String Key="my-key";
byte[] KeyByteArray=Key.getBytes("UTF-8");

byte[] signature=RawData.getBytes("UTF-8");


Mac sha256_HMAC;
sha256_HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");

SecretKeySpec secret_key = new SecretKeySpec(KeyByteArray, "HmacSHA256");
    sha256_HMAC.init(secret_key);
String ContentBase64String = Base64.encodeToString(sha256_HMAC.doFinal(signature),Base64.URL_SAFE|Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

The output for C# is as follows:
[image: C# output]
The output for android is as follows:
[image: Android Output]

I have been it at it for many days and can't figure out what I am doing wrong as the outputs differ though they should be the same.**Also, when I remove the - in the key the results are the same**. I know I might be missing something simple but thought another pair of eyes might see my mistake. Thanks.

Comment: There is the minor diff. The "-" in android is shown as "+" in c#. Look towards the end. I have mentioned this in the second last line of the question

Comment: Moreover if a / is present in one it is shown as _ in the other. The rest matches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those answers are the same (as far as the bytes contained in the HMAC goes). For the difference in the `+` and `-` characters in the output, you *specifically told it to do that* by specifying [the `Base64.URL_SAFE` flag](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html#URL_SAFE).

For future readers of this question: When in doubt, consult the documentation for everything you don't perfectly understand.